# how is it possible to use backbonejs on server-side? (on nodejs)

Tags: backbone.js

Is Backbone.js a web framework for client-side? or both?

I have known that backbonejs is using for client-side so as some examples on backbone.js those examples are loading backbone.js using . But I can search and download backbone module (for nodejs) from npm and there are some approaches to use backbonejs on the server-side.

How is it possible?
And is using backbonejs on the server-side intended by founder of backbonejs ?

Comment: There have been attempts but it's not a natural fit, trying googling "isomorphic backbone"

Comment: I'd say no, that probably wasn't the intention of the creator of `backbone.js`. I wonder what people are going to do with `Backbone.View` on server side. `view.$el` on serverside where there is no `DOM`..? lol